# Installing windows 8.1 on Mac via bootcamp from a licensed DVD without a USB drive?

Tags: mac, windows-8.1, boot-camp

Can I use a store bought DVD version of Windows 8.1 to install on my Mac ?

I have a DVD reader and the actual 64bit DVD. Do I still need to generate an `.iso` file and run it on a USB drive?

Comment: Yes you can....

Comment: great. how? its always asking me to provide a USB drive

Comment: Yes you would need to create an image of your disk

Answer (score -1):

Below are the steps for installing Windows on a Mac using boot camp as mentioned in [HT201468](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201468)

1. Check System requirements
2. **Create a disk image of your Windows disc**
3. Open Boot Camp Assistant
4. Format your Windows partition
5. Install Windows
6. Restart your computer

Comment: the instruction you point to mentions that you need A 16 GB or larger USB 2 flash drive that you can erase, which is not what im looking for

Comment: What is your problem ? Not having a 16GB flash drive or not having one at all ?

Comment: hehe. not having one at all.

Comment: Flash Drive is must as it would be required to access Windows installation files after it reboots and have no access to Macintosh HD